# How do you display the contents of a string using the position of a substring as a starting point?

Tags: c++, string, find

Is it posible to cout a string from a position gained by using string.find to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible, and in more ways than one. `string.find()` returns a position, so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "This is a test";
    std::string::size_type pos = str.find("test");
    if(pos != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << str.substr(pos) << '\n';
}
```

or with iterators if you're afraid `substr()` will create an unnecessary temporary

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "This is a test";
    std::string::size_type pos = str.find("test");
    if(pos != std::string::npos)
        copy(str.begin() + pos, str.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::cout << yourStr.substr(yourStr.find("position"));
```

Check out the [substr method reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Answer (score 3):

Sure. `string::find` returns an index and `string::substr` takes an index for the starting position (and ending position, but in this case you can use the default), so you could do something like this:

```
std::cout << mystring.substr(mystring.find("Whatever"));
```

Answer (score 2):

[`string.find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) returns a size_t for the index in the string where it finds what you were searching for.  If it's not `npos`, you can substr it:

```
size_t pos = str.find("whatever");
if (pos != std::string::npos) {
  std::cout << str.substr(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const string s("So close no matter how far");
    const string::size_type pos = s.find("no");
    if (pos != string::npos) {
        cout << &s[pos] << endl;
    }
}
```